# Installing and using Leptonica library on Windows with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, lib, leptonica

What I did:

1. Downloaded sw, leptonica source and cmake.
2. Executed 'ms build' in leptonica source directory -> '.sw' folder.
3. Build a visual studio project from the leptonica source with cmake -> 'build' folder.
4. Opened the project and build it (debug, 64x) -> 'leptonica-1.82.0d.lib' file.
5. Created a new project (debug, 64x) and included leptonica 'allheaders.h' file.

   - Additional Include Directories:

     - C:...\c++ libraries
     - C:...\c++ libraries\leptonica-1.82.0\build\src (for endianness.h)
6. Linked 'leptonica-1.82.0d.lib':

   - Additional Library Directory:

     - C:...\c++ libraries\leptonica-1.82.0\build\src\Debug
   - Additional Dependencies:

     - leptonica-1.82.0d.lib

When I want to execute the following program, I get many 'unresolved external symbol' errors.

```
#include <leptonica-1.82.0/src/allheaders.h>
int main()
{
    Pix* image = pixRead("imagePath");
}
```

What am I missing? Is there an additional DLL file?

Comment: Why not make your life far easier and use [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) for installing dependencies. [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) also has great Visual Studio integration

Comment: No, these are linker errors that are not caused by missing DLL but because libs of dependencies were not added as Additional dependencies.

Comment: Thanks guys. After a little bit more searchy serachy I discovered that Leptonica depends on several I/O libraries (libjpeg, libtiff, libpng, libz, libwebp, libgif, libopenjp2). I will make my live easier and try it with vcpkg.

Comment: vcpkg worked great!